# Getting errors when change AppDelegate.m to .mm

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an issue in changing from .m to .mm extension. I have an appdelegate class. Initially it is .m but for including the c++ code I have changed it to .mm but I am getting the issues at lines **CFArrayRef myArray = CNCopySupportedInterfaces(); and CFDictionaryRef myDict = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(myArray, 0));**

**Errors**

1.Use of undeclared identifier CNCopySupportedInterfaces

2.Use of undeclared identifier CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo

```
-(NSString*)getWifiInfo
{
    CFArrayRef myArray = CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
    CFDictionaryRef myDict = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(myArray, 0));
    //NSLog(@"Connected at:%@",myDict);
    NSDictionary *myDictionary = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary*)myDict;
    //NSString * BSSID = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"BSSID"];
    NSString * SSID = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"SSID"];

    return SSID;
    //NSLog(@"ssid is %@",SSID);
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
}
```

I have imported   but didn't fixed my issue.

Comment: might be because application delegate don't support c++ code, try using singleton and call that in your application delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Rename file **AppDelegate.m** to **.mm** not enough, because IDE still print strange errors like:

- Unknown type name class; Did you mean Class?
- Expected ; after top level declared

For fix that need a rename **main.m** file to **main.mm** also, keep that in mind.

Also make sure the type of **.mm** file is set to **Objective-C++ Source**
(Click to file -> Inspector Property -> Type)

Answer (score 0):

When changing AppDelegate.m to AppDelegate.mm, you need to:

- also change main.m to main.mm
- then open yourappname.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj file and rename all instances of "AppDelegate.m" to "AppDelegate.mm", same for "main.m" to "main.mm"

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to change the Application Delegate to .mm .
"**CNCopySupportedInterfaces**" and "**CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo**" are both declared in framework **SystemConfiguration/CaptiveNetwork.h**. Also, if you will check all other objects used in your method, you will find out that all of them are part of Objective-C frameworks.

You should use .mm in other cases, like including a C++ library. It's not the case here. You can use C++ syntax in your .m files without worries as long as you don't have any C++ dependencies that would require using the Obj-C++ compiler.

Change the class back to .m, be sure to add the SystemConfiguration framework into your project ([tutorial here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html)) and then import the CaptiveNetwork in the Application delegate :

```
#import <SystemConfiguration/CaptiveNetwork.h>
```

I was able to build your method in my own app delegate.